# get magento order id from customer data

Tags: php, sql, magento, collections

I'm having problems getting a collection with join working.  I'm trying to get the order ID's connected to customer telephone numbers, saved in `sales_flat_order_address`. So a join on the collection with `sales/order` and a filter based on the variable with my phone number in it. I've tried all sorts of combinations, but so far I only get errors and right now I've deleted my code and will try from scratch.  Any ideas or links to tutorials about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small code snippet below

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', value)->load();
//Here your attribute code is phone
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel(’sales/order’)->getCollection();
$orderCollection->getSelect()->where(’e.customer_id =’.$customer->getId());
```

:)

Comment: Thanks, but `customer/customer` doesn't seem to include the billing or shipping information, like telephone or address. I'll look into that and see if I can somehow get to it.

Comment: use customer/address in that case